# Can I add a custom UIGestureRecognizer subclass to a UIView in my Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, uigesturerecognizer, uistoryboard

Is this possible? I've made a custom UIGestureRecognizer subclass and want to attach it to a view in my Storyboard. Is this possible to do without doing it programmatically?

Comment: This looks promising: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/11/24/creating-gesture-recognizers-with-interface-builder.html.  (ps - I googled the title of your post, this is a good step before posting).

Comment: @danh Those are using Apple's default `UIGestureRecognizer` subclasses. I want to create my own and use it.

Comment: Oh gotcha.  Will create an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Gesture Recognizers are available in Interface Builder (see [this tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/11/24/creating-gesture-recognizers-with-interface-builder.html)). Apple's derived UIGestureRecognizer subclasses are the only ones that show up but it looks to me like you can use your own subclass.

In order to get the subclass to stick I had to make my UIGestureRecognizer subclass a subclass of the Apple recognizer I added in IB, change the class to my subclass in Interface Builder, and then change it back to a UIGestureRecognizer subclass.

Comment: This seems very prone to breaking in a future release would it not?

Comment: @DougSmith possibly. You can't be 100% sure what Interface Builder is doing with those gesture recognizers. If you want to ensure that future Xcode updates won't break things, I would create them in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an outlet to and instantiate any object in IB -- subclass of an SDK class or not -- by adding a generic object to a scene.  Search for "NSObject" in the IB Object library, and drag it in.

Once you've done that, change it's class in the class inspector to your GR subclass and create an outlet the way you normally would.  In viewDidLoad (or awakeFromNib), set the outlet's view and it's target/action.

Doing all this let's IB instantiate your custom gr.  What this idea doesn't do is to get the view and target set in IB.  I can't imagine why that would be needed (vs. code) but maybe you have a good reason I can't think of.